# Container exits if invoked from compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a dockerized server process that merely listens on a port 5000

```
[admin@gol05854 compose]$ cat ../proc1/server.sh
#!/bin/sh

echo `date` "Starting server"

nc -v -l -p 5000

echo `date` "Exiting server"
```

I have a client that is expected to continuously send messages to the server:

```
[admin@gol05854 compose]$ cat ../client/client.sh
#!/bin/sh

echo `date` "Starting client"

while true
do
date
done | nc my_server 5000

echo `date` "Ending client"
```

I start these together using compose. However, the server exits with following messages:

```
[admin@gol05854 compose]$ docker logs e1_my_server_1  
Wed Oct 26 04:10:34 UTC 2016 Starting server  
listening on [::]:5000 ...  
connect to [::ffff:172.27.0.2]:5000 from e1_my_client_1_1.e1_default:36500 ([::ffff:172.27.0.3]:36500)  
Wed Oct 26 04:10:36 UTC 2016  
Wed Oct 26 04:10:36 UTC 2016  
Wed Oct 26 04:10:36 UTC 2016  
Wed Oct 26 04:10:36 UTC 2016  
Wed Oct 26 04:10:36 UTC 2016 
Exiting server
```

What is surprising is that if the same containers are started without compose, using docker run, the server remains running.

What is it that docker compose does that causes the server to exit after receiving a few messages?

The code can be found at https://github.com/yashgt/dockerpoc

Comment: Could you at least update your git repository so that it is usable "out of the box"? The build instructions are disabled, so there's no way to tell if we're testing the same thing you're testing, because maybe you just have stale images.  If you actually want someone to look at it, checking out the repository and running "docker-compose up" should demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Instructions: Go to proc1 directory and run build.sh. Go to client folder and invoke build.sh. This should get the two images created. Go to compose folder and invoke run.sh to invoke docker-compose up.

Comment: What `docker run` command do you use? If you set `-i -t` then you have to do the same in the Compose file with `tty: true, stdin_open: true`.

Comment: I will try the options and let you know. However, I still wonder why the server runs for some time and stops. If there was something seriously incorrect, the server would not have run at all.